# Xcode commit: Couldn't communicate with helper application

Tags: ios, github, git-commit

I have tried to commit the code in GitHub repository, but I am getting the error:

> Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.

How to commit the code via terminal?

I'm using Xcode 10.

Comment: What software that give you the error? The git cli or some gui git tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting Author name and Author email into **Xcode -> Preference -> Sorce Control -> git** working for me.

[image]